# Replacing duplicates in a string

Tags: c++, replace

I am trying to write a code to replace duplicates in string by '*' . The code I have written is-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
  string ch;
  cin>>ch;
  for(int i=0;i<ch.length()&& (ch[i]!='*');i++)
  {
      for(int j=i+1;j<ch.length()&&ch[j]!='*';j++)   
      {
        if(ch[i]==ch[j])ch[j]='*';
      }
  }
    cout<<ch;
}
```

The above code gives unexpected results for some inputs. 
For e.g. if the input is "adad" the answer I get is "ad*d", whereas the output for "adda", and "aadd" matches the expected output. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: because your loops stop on first `*` encountered, it should be an `if` condition inside those loops, not a loop-break condition

Comment: that is perfect task to learn programming so I will feel very guilty if I help you

Comment: if you use `getline` for the input then you can also get a string with spaces.

Comment: when you get this to work, consider how to reduce the complexity (and thus time) from quadratic to linear.

Comment: @PiotrS. i tried your suggestion and the code seems to work fine now :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yeah I will work on that now

Comment: as I see now that some people have also answered with the correct code , which one should I mark as the correct answer (although my mistake was pointed out first in a comment )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Piotr S. said in the comments, you need to keep processing the string, even if the current character is `*`. Here is my take, this should work:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string ch;
    cin >> ch;
    for(int i = 0; i < ch.length(); ++i)
    {
        if(ch[i] == '*') continue; // skip this entry
        for(int j = i + 1; j < ch.length(); ++j)   
        {
            if(ch[i] == ch[j]) ch[j]='*';
        }
    }
    cout<<ch;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for the above algorithm to remove the duplicates instead of replacing them with an alternate character, by doing some minor changes ?

Comment: Yes, you could use std::string::erase() (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/), however in this example it might be easiest to create a new `string output`, and append every char that isn't a duplicate. Changing a item you are iterating over is always tricky, if not dangerous, so easiest would be to do something like this: https://www.systemli.org/paste/?f41f40b15dac7c1f#/OnuBuY3MsBcBhuR8+dTKpEyqk1PqF0ujEM3x3hXJRg=

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** **Your for loop will break as soon as the loop condition returns false**. adad changes to ad*d after the first iteration of the outer for loop. But then `i` gets set to `1`, `j` is set to `2`. Will your second for loop execute with these values?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is:

You are stopping outer loop if you encounter `*`. Now, suppose input is `abcabc`. In first iteration of outer loop you will change it to `abc*bc`. In second Iteration of outer loop inner loop will encounter `*` and will exit (without changing `b` to `*`). Same thing will happen to third iteration of outer loop. In fourth iteration of outer loop exit condition (`ch[i] != '*'`) will become false and your program will exit. Here is a fix:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string ch;
    cin >> ch;
    for(int i=0; i < ch.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < ch.length(); j++)     
        {
            if(ch[i] == ch[j] && ch[i] != '*')
                ch[j]='*';
        }
    }
    cout << ch << endl;
}
```